# 'Spotty' meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "Here come Ernie and Hannah Abbott," said Ron, looking over his shoulder. "And those Ravenclaw blokes and Smith ... and no one looks very **spotty**."
>
> Hermione looked alarmed.
>
> "Never mind **spots**, the idiots can't come over here now, it'll look really suspicious - sit down!" she mouthed to Ernie and Hannah, gesturing frantically to them to rejoin the Hufflepuff table.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

According to dictionaries, *spotty*:

> 1. someone who is spotty has small raised red marks on their skin, especially on their face
> 2. good only in some parts, but not in other parts

But none of them seems to fit for the context. What does it mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the first definition, and it also is used to refer to acne/pimples.

If you recall earlier in the book, Hermione puts a jinx on the sign-up sheet for the D.A. that anyone who reveals the secret meeting place will get cursed with bad acne. They think they've been betrayed, so they're looking for the person who has new "spots" to figure out who told on them.